# Scrapy: extracting data from an html tag that uses an "id" Selector instead of a "class"

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to web scraping and Scrapy. I hope you can help me.

I am trying to extract data from a web page where it uses  tag. Usually, if the span tag is using a class, for example:

```
<span class="class_A>Hello, World!</span>
```

I would use the following code to retrieve the text.

```
request.css('span.class_A::text').extract()
```

However, when an html is now using an "id" instead of a "class", for example,

```
<span id="id_A>Hello, Universe!</span>
```

the code below does not work anymore.

```
request.css('span.id_A::text').extract()
```

Please help! What's the correct way of extracting data using an "id".

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 13):

This is one way.

```
>>> HTML = '''
... <span id="id_A">Hello, Earth</span>
... <span id="id_B">Hello, Universe</span>
... '''
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=HTML)
>>> selector.css('[id="id_A"]::text').extract()
['Hello, Earth']
```

Alternatively,

```
>>> HTML = '''
... <span id="id_A">Hello, Earth</span>
... <span id="id_B">Hello, Universe</span>
... '''
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=HTML)
>>> selector.css('span#id_A::text').extract()
['Hello, Earth']
```

Scrapy uses [cssselect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect/) which follows [W3 Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Comment: hi, thank you. how do I do this without typing the html codes?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're using a "class selector" (please check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for reference). You should really use an "id selector", this should work:

```
response.css('#id_A::text').extract()
```

Comment: hi, thank you. But, this is still giving an empty list.

Comment: what the heck, I tried this multiple times. It did not work. Now, when I tried it with another span having a different id, it worked. Then, I tried it back again with this <span id='id_A'>, it already worked? What just happened? When I reviewed everything it was just all the same. but, THANK YOU SO MUCH! I'm very happy with your help. It helps me a lot, but I'm still trying to figure out what just happened.